# How to right click items repeatedly with redstone/command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have made a command block system that `testfor`s when you have a blaze rod in your first slot and it's highlighted. If this all comes out true, then it will summon an armor stand, where another command searches when a blaze rod is placed in his hand. Then it executes a command that teleports you up higher.

So basically, what's happening is when you right-click the blaze rod, it will teleport you higher up.

**My question:** After teleporting me, how can I make the blaze rod "reset" so, I can just right-click it again as many times as I want without having to unselect it, and move to a different inventory slot, and go back on the blaze rod slot again. For, my system only resets when you hover on a different slot, rather than staying on the same slot and using the system repeatedly. I want it so you can stay on the same slot and use it many times.

Any ways to accomplish this?

[image]

Here is a picture of what my machine looks like.

Test for commands next to redstone block.
   Testfor armor stand holding blaze rod on left side
   Testfor player holding rod, selected in first slot on right side

Far right: Kills armorstand if blaze rod on slot 1 is NOT selected.

Top: summons the armor stand that follows player

Left: once armor stand has blaze rod, it gets removed, players inventoy cleared, a new blaze rod is placed, and it teleports player upward.

This is being used in 1.9, 15w46.

Is there any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out all I had to do was to add this little part:

[image]

I set up a command block that replaced the redstone wire, and it was always activated.

Comment: Nice! @Akidus!!